# How can I ensure that the script defining an img.onload function loads before the img?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

Suppose my HTML contains these two tags in the order shown:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<img src="http://otherdomain.com/image.png" onload="imgLoad(this)"/>
```

And `script.js` defines the function `imgLoad`. I understand that as the browser parses the HTML it will see the script first and thus request it first, but if that takes a long time and the image finishes loading before the script, I will get an error that `imgLoad` is undefined.

Or is that not actually possible? Does the spec require that onload events and the running of javascript happen synchronously in the order the elements are declared? If so, do modern browsers implement this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [great article](http://trevweb.me.uk/javascripthtml-synchronous-and-asynchronous-loading/) on the subject.

## TL;DR

It is not possible for the image to load before the script, as script loading is synchronous. This is the easiest way to create a loading functionality for a browser and is, therefore, the default functionality for all modern browsers.